# How do I get the SQL Where clause to handle TWO StringVariables?

Tags: asp.net

I pass TWO StringQueries to new page: `/Find.aspx?Color=Blue&Shape=Round`

In my Products.aspx I have a GridView with a SelectCommand:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Name], [Price], [ProductNo] 
               FROM [MSD_Store] WHERE ([Color] = ?)"
```

How do I get the Where clause to handle TWO StringVariables?

Comment: Isn't this just a case of adding "and"?  Where ([color]=?) and ([shape]=?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add necessary part of the SQL query and define another query string parameter:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Name], [Price], [ProductNo] FROM [MSD_Store] WHERE ([Color] = ?) AND ([Shape] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="Color" Name="color" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="Shape" Name="shape" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked thanks!  I had the Select parameters in the wrong order: shape before color. I switched it to match your code and presto. Thank you very much Andrei!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing
SelectCommand: SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Name], [Price], [ProductNo] FROM [MSD_Store] WHERE ([Color] = ? AND [Shape = ?])

and then you add another parameter definition, reading your querystring value

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Name], [Price], [ProductNo] 
FROM [MSD_Store] WHERE ([Color] = ?) AND ([Shape] = ?)
```

by "two" string variables?

Comment: Mithrandir - I had tried that before but it returned an empty container. no error, just empty.